# Custom Method wont display StreamReader inputfile texts

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, while-loop, streamreader

I currently have it in my form1 as that's the only way it works. I need to put it into a custom Method that will display the content when the form loads up. Any suggestions? I tried putting it before form1 that didn't work. I tried calling the method into their event handlers. No success (This is on Winforms).

```
   private void PopulateBoxes()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText("Occassions.txt");
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                occasionsComboBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
            }
            inputFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText("Extras.txt");
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                ExtrasListBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
            }
            inputFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file

Comment: Try to provide the file path along with file name. `inputFile = File.OpenText("D:\\Extras.txt");`